# iOS message view control like the iMessage

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Are there any UI control library which has iMessage similar functionalities, e.g. can display message, image etc

Or in fact is it part of the iOS standard so I can re-use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [acaniChat](https://github.com/acani/acaniChat). That's what you're looking for - or at least you can take all you need from it.